# Ordering of KSOAP elements

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap

I've been using KSOAP for Android to send SOAP requests containing 6 elements, the last of which is an array of values. Here's the code ...

```
       PropertyInfo properties[] = new PropertyInfo[numberOfProperties]; 
       properties[0] = new UserLogin("user2"); 
       properties[1] = new UserPassword("u2");
       properties[2] = new MAC_ID("00:01:02:03:04:05"); 
       properties[3] = new StartMeasurement(mStartTime);
       properties[4] = new StopMeasurement(mStopTime);

       SoapObject soapObjectRequest = new SoapObject(ROOT_NAMESPACE, mSoapMethodName);

       for(int i=0;i< properties.length;i++)
        soapObjectRequest.addProperty(properties[i]); 

       SoapObject eventList = new SoapObject(ROOT_NAMESPACE, "eventValues"); 

       SoapObject eventValues = new SoapObject(TYPE_NAMESPACE, "EventValues");

       eventValues.addProperty(9.9);

       eventValues.addProperty(101.1);

       eventList.addSoapObject(eventValues);

       soapObjectRequest.addSoapObject(eventList);
```

Everything works fine in the request, bar the ordering. When I call addSoapObject, it places the array values first in the body request. So everything inside the eventValues element appears at the top of the request.  It should be the last element for the request to succeed. All other property elements are in the correct order.

Is there some way to dictate the order to KSOAP? I'm using version 2.6.0.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What are u trying to do ..i couldnt understand and what is ur issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it here is a patch and lib ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.1--jar-with-dependencies.jar
http://fbe.am/3k <---- 2 patches and lib

Here is the topic: http://groups.google.com/group/ksoap2-android/browse_thread/thread/1ee05350dd8c041

Thx a lot to Andrew O. here is his repo with fixes too (patches are generated from him) http://github.com/Usagimaru57/ksoap2-android

It works for me.